# Simple pagination in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am working with simple pagination in laravel. I am fetching 20 records from the database in a foreach loop and making a quiz. I want to skip some question in between quiz by applying if condition in controller part...like I want to skip question number 10 and 11. How to proceed in simple pagination?

Controller part :

```
public function choosequestion(Request $request){

    if(Session::get('storepercentage')  < 60){

        $getquestion = DB::table('5question')->select('question_id','question','choice1','choice2','choice3','choice4','question_level')
                                               ->where('question_level','=','easy')
                                               ->simplepaginate(1);
    }

    if(Session::get('storepercentage')  > 60){ 

        $getquestion = DB::table('5question')->select('question_id','question','choice1','choice2','choice3','choice4','question_level')
                                               ->where('question_level','=','medium')
                                               ->simplepaginate(1);
    } 

    if($request->ajax()){

        return view('ajax',['getquestions'=>$getquestion])->render();
    }

    return view('question5',['getquestions'=>$getquestion]);
}
```

Controller input part to calaculate % :

```
public  function questionquiz5(Request $request){

    static $startscore=0;
    static $getscore;
    static $level;

    $getidvalue = Input::get('getid');
    $getanswervalue = Input::get('getanswer');

    $dbscore = \DB::table('5question')->select('question_id','correct_answer','question_marks','question_level')
                                      ->where('question_id','=',$getidvalue)
                                      ->get();


    foreach ($dbscore as $easy) {//////easy questions start 

        if ( $getanswervalue==($easy->correct_answer) ){

             $level = $easy->question_level;  
             $getscore  =  $startscore + $easy->question_marks;

        }elseif($getanswervalue == null){

             $getscore = 0;
             $level = $easy->question_level;   

        }else{

             $getscore = 0;
             $level = $easy->question_level;

        }

    }

    Session::push('getscoresession',$getscore);
    $score = array_sum(Session::get("getscoresession"));

    $epercentage = ($score / 8 ) * 100; 

    if($epercentage > 60){
            Session::put('storepercentage', $epercentage);
            echo "true";
            echo $epercentage;                                       
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }


    Session::push('level',$level);

    $getsession = [  'qid' => $getidvalue,  'answer' => $getanswervalue];

    Session::push('answer', $getsession);
}
```

My issue is that I am getting a blank view for the second condition in simple pagination can we skip question like this?

Comment: use paginate( https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination )

Comment: You are using `if ($percentage < 60)` and `if ($percentage > 60)` - what happens for `if ($percentage == 60)`? You might want to make one of these conditions `>=` or `<=`.

Comment: @GauravGupta, not even by using the paginate method.

Comment: @Namoshek....i have 20 question in database ..8 easy level ...8 medium...4 hard type if I an using if ($percentage < 60) I am getting the easy question on my view using simple pagination but  if ($percentage > 60) I want to skip some questions like don't want 7 and 8th question and start with  9th question... I am getting my medium question but from 14 or 15....

Comment: Of course, I understand that. But currently you don't select any questions `if ($percentage == 60)`, only if you are below or above 60% (so with 20 questions this will definitely break at some point). You could add `dd($getquestion);` just before `if($request->ajax())` to see what your queries return. Try it once for a working page and once for the one that is not working.

Comment: @Namoshek  if ($percentage == 60 ||  $percentage > 60)...not getting anything from this query ...dd/print_r  print only question which i am getting on view.....Thanks for understanding as well...